# vue-qrcode-component can't keep the quotes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to create a JSON string and then turn it into a QRCode using `vue-qrcode-component`. This is where I am creating the string:

```
this.qrCode = "{‘type’:’serialNumber’,’id’:25434,’stock_id’:736,’stock_order_id’:’655’}";
```

And then in the template:

```
<qr-code :text="qrCode"></qr-code>
```

But I keep getting this when scanning the generated qr:

```
{type:serialNumber,id:25434,stock_id:736,stock_order_id:655}
```

So I am losing the quotes which I need for it to be formatted correctly. I have tried escaping `'` with ` but this hasn't worked

Any suggestions

Comment: [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)?

Comment: But it has to be passed into the component as text will that work?

Comment: With JSON probably yes (if the component expects JSON). But probably not with your string as defined in `this.qrCode`. That is neither JSON nor a JavaScript object.

Comment: Yeah it expects a string, I think the component is likely removing the quotes

Comment: Why do you have those strange quotes in the first place? It just makes parsing it more complicated. If you think this is JSON, it is not.

Comment: Actually `JSON.stringify` worked a treat thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `JSON.stringify` worked a treat